# whats the purpose of using this mybase keyword without this keyword also this code still runs without errors

Tags: c#, vb.net, infragistics

```
Public Overrides Sub AddGridColumns()
            Try
                'Copy and delete columns
                Me.iLeuUltraGrid.AssignColumnStyle("Copy", "", 0, , _                        LEU.Controls.ExtInfragistics.LEUUltraGrid.LEUColumnStyleEnum.Image, _                                   LEU.Controls.ExtInfragistics.LEUUltraGrid.LEUDynamicEnum.DefaultFalse _
                                   , , , , , , , , , , , , , , "GRID_IMAGE_COPY", False)
               Me.iLeuUltraGrid.AssignColumnStyle("Delete", "", 1, , _
                    LEU.Controls.ExtInfragistics.LEUUltraGrid.LEUColumnStyleEnum.Image, _
                    LEU.Controls.ExtInfragistics.LEUUltraGrid.LEUDynamicEnum.DefaultFalse _
                    , , , , , , , , , , , , , , "GRID_IMAGE_DELETE", False)

                MyBase.AddGridColumns()
```

Comment: Purpose of `MyBase.AddGridColumns()` is to call the baseclass method which you are overriding.

Answer (score 0):

[MyBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzfhkk01%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) provides a way to refer to the base class of the current instance so in this example it calls the AddGridColumns method that was overridden in the base class.  If you remove MyBase then the call to AddGridColumns would be to the one in the current instance and it would be recursively called until there is a StackOverflowException thrown.

Note that you likely don't see the StackOverflowException because this is being thrown within a try block and you are likely handling the exception.